# Class with no apparent styling on Bootstrap website

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am customizing a Bootstrap template and am trying to understand the code in it so I can code similar sites myself in the future. I don't think it's necessary to look at the template, but if you're interested, the link is here: [Dance Whirl](https://w3layouts.com/dance-whirl-entertainment-category-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/)

The website seems to have several classes and a few ID's that have absolutely no styling or script in either the CSS or JS files. There are in fact 7 CSS files and 12 JS files for the template. I wrote down a list of all classes and IDs in the HTML and searched each file for them, and several were missing.

Right now I'm wondering about the class "slider". It is a div that contains other divs and content constituting a carousel and banner image. I can't find any reference to slider in any of the other files, including the downloaded bootstrap files. I've also searched the internet for class="slider", bootstrap slider, and bootstrap class="slider", and I can't find anything suggesting that this is a bootstrap class.

Am I missing something? Is slider in fact a bootstrap-specific class? If not, is there a particular reason for including a class with no styling in a div?

Here is a clip of the code in question:`

```
    <!-- banner-text -->
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="callbacks_container">
            <ul class="rslides callbacks callbacks1" id="slider4">
                <li>
                    <div class="w3layouts-banner-top">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="agileits-banner-info">
                                <h3>Shall We <span>Dance</span> ?</h3>
                                    <p>CELEBRATE YOUR EVENT WITH US</p>
                                <div class="agileits_w3layouts_more menu__item">
            <a href="#" class="menu__link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Learn More</a>
        </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>`
```

Comment: _"Is slider in fact a bootstrap-specific class?"_ No. _"is there a particular reason for including a class with no styling in a div?"_ No, however it may be being manipulated via JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

It's not an official Bootstrap class. I wouldn't worry about it. Sometimes people apply classes to make the structure of the markup more understandable, or because they expect to need to style that element (which they then discover is not true).